# Fill an Excelsheet with List<> entries

Tags: c#

I´ve got a List<> with different entries, every entrie exists out of several elements. (brand, version, variant)

```
List<car> carList = new List<car>();
```

The carList includes the elements: brand, version, variant
This is my code actually:

```
public partial class MainForm
{
    public void ProtokollToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application ExcelApplication;
        Excel._Workbook ExcelWorkbook;
        Excel._Worksheet ExcelWorksheet;

        try
        {
            //Start Excel
            ExcelApplication = new Excel.Application();
            ExcelApplication.Visible = true;                
            //New Workbook/Worksheet
            ExcelWorkbook = (Excel._Workbook)(ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
            ExcelWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;               
            //Counter
            int countplus1 = 0;
            int countplus4 = 0;

            foreach (car A in carList)
            {               
                //Fill the List
                countplus1 += 1;
                countplus4 += 4;
                ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4, 2] = "Brand:";
                ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4 + 1, 2] = "Version:";
                ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4 + 2, 2] = "Variant:";
                ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4, 3] = A.CarBrand;
                ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4 + 1, 3] = A.CarVersion;
                ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4 + 2, 3] = A.CarVariant;
            }   
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

At the moment my Excelsheet looks like that:

```
    {
    Brand:      Audi
    Version:    A4
    Variant:    Limousine

    Brand:      VW
    Version:    Golf
    Variant:    Limousine

    Brand:      Audi
    Version:    A3
    Variant:    Wagon

    Brand:      Audi
    Version:    A4
    Variant:    Limousine
}
```

Now I Want that the excelsheet looks like that:

```
    {
    Brand:      Audi
    Version:    A4
    Variant:    Limousine
                Wagon
                Coupe

    Version:    A3
    Variant:    Limousine
                Wagon       

    Brand:      VW
    Version:    Golf
    Variant:    Limousine
                Coupe
}
```

Can Someone help me, I don´t now how to do this? Maybe with try & cath?

Thank you all

Comment: I see you want multi-level grouping, which is fine, but your posting is unclear about the indentation.

Comment: What exactly is unclear?

Comment: Your post shows the groups are somewhat indented. Is that intentional?

Comment: Now that is not intentional. I only thought then it´s
more unambiguously!

Comment: Is this homework? if so, please tag it as such

Comment: No these are no homework! I need this issue for a protocol

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post what the `Car` class looks like, i'm going to need to assume that `Car` looks like this :

```
public class Car
{
  public String CarBrand{ get; set; }
  public String CarVersion{ get; set; }

  //if this is only a single string, you will need to change it.
  public List<String> Variants { get; set; }
}
```

you can then do this :

```
public void ProtokollToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application ExcelApplication;
    Excel._Workbook ExcelWorkbook;
    Excel._Worksheet ExcelWorksheet;

    try
    {
        //Start Excel
        ExcelApplication = new Excel.Application();
        ExcelApplication.Visible = true;                
        //New Workbook/Worksheet
        ExcelWorkbook = (Excel._Workbook)(ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
        ExcelWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;               
        //Counter

        int countplus1 = 0;
        int countplus4 = 0;

        foreach (Car A in carList)
        {               
            //Fill the List
            countplus1 += 1;
            countplus4 += 4;
            ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4, 2] = "Brand:";
            ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4 + 1, 2] = "Version:";
            ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4 + 2, 2] = "Variant:";

            ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4, 3] = A.CarBrand;
            ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4 + 1, 3] = A.CarVersion;

            if(A.Variants == null) continue;

            foreach(String variant in A.Variants)
            {
                ExcelSheet.Cells[3 + countplus4 + (A.Variants.IndexOf(variant)+2), 3] = variant;
            }
        }   
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to group your data by Brand and then by Version. You can do this using Linq.

To do a single-level grouping (e.g. by brand) you'd want this:

```
IGrouping<String,Car> carsByBrand = cars.GroupBy( car => car.Brand );
```

But to do a multi-level grouping, we first group-by the innermost criterion (the `Version`) then combine all of those together (`SelectMany`) and then group-by the `Brand`:

```
var carsByBrandByVersion =
    cars.GroupBy( car => car.Version ).
    SelectMany(
        g => g.GroupBy( g2 => g2.Brand )
    );
```

When this collection is enumerated you'll get the result you're after:

```
foreach(var brandGroup in carsByBrandByVersion) {
    Console.WriteLine("Brand: {0}", brandGroup.Key );
    foreach(var versionGroup in brandGroup) {
        Console.WriteLine("    Version: {0}", versionGroup.Key );
        foreach(Car car in versionGroup ) {
            Console.WriteLine("        Variant: {0}", car.Variant );
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you console output in the desired format, converting it to use Excel should be a trivial matter :)